# Error during template compile of 'Injectable' Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called

Tags: node.js, angular, ng-packagr

I am trying to create an angular package using ng-packagr.

I have added the following script into my package json in order to build the package

```
"scripts": {
"build:lib": "ng-packagr -p lib/package.json"},
```

However, I am getting the following errors when I run the build command.

[image]
[image]